# When using Hibernate-GORM, how to convert domain class into JSON string?

Tags: json, hibernate, grails-orm, micronaut

For using Hibernate-GORM in Micronaut 1.1.1, I use below command to create a micronaut app:

`mn create-app foo -l=groovy -f=hibernate-gorm`

And, for adding the ability of approaching JSON , I add below line to build.gradle in order to use JsonSlurper to approace JSON:

`compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6'`

So my build.gralde looks like below:

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "groovy"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "4.0.2"
    id "application"
}

version "0.1"
group "memberservice"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:1.1.1'
    }
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly 
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6'
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime-groovy"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-validator"
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-gorm"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testCompile "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "memberservice.Application"
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs.add('-Dgroovy.parameters=true')
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

run.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
run.jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
```

Now I have a domain class as below:

```
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Member {
    String memberId
    String email

    static constraints = {
        memberId    maxSize: 20, nullable: false, unique: true
        email       maxSize: 60, nullable: false
    }
}
```

And I have a controller as below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import memberservice.domain.Member

@Slf4j
@Controller('/member')
class MemberController {


    @Get('/testFetchMember')
    def testFetchMember() {
        Member member
        Member.withTransaction {
            member = Member.findByMemberId('A0001')
        }
        log.info("member.email is ${member.email}")
        def jsonObject = new JsonBuilder(member)
        log.info("check point 1001: finish JsonBuilder")
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toPrettyString()
        log.info("jsonString=" + jsonString)
        return jsonString
    }

    @Get('/buildSampleData')
    def buildSampleData() {
        Member member = new Member()
        member.with {
            memberId = 'A0001'
            email = 'foo@gmail.com'
        }
        Member.withTransaction {
            member.save()
//            new Member(memberId: 'A0002', 'foo1@mail.com').save()
//            new Member(memberId: 'A0003', 'foo2@mail.com').save()
        }
        return "Sample data built done"
    }
}
```

Below are output log:

```
09:23:30.610 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  m.controller.MemberController - member.email is foo@gmail.com
09:23:30.619 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  m.controller.MemberController - check point 1001: finish JsonBuilder
09:23:31.069 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: null
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
at groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:59)
at groovy.lang.PropertyValue.getValue(PropertyValue.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getProperties(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:557)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.getObjectProperties(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:242)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:236)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:387)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMap(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:375)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:237)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:164)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeIterator(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:402)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeArray(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:285)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:221)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:387)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMap(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:375)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:237)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:164)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeIterator(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:402)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeArray(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:285)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:221)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:387)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMap(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:375)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:237)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:164)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeIterator(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:402)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeArray(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:285)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:221)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:387)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMap(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:375)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:237)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:164)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeIterator(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:402)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeArray(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:285)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:221)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:387)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMap(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:375)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:237)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:164)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeIterator(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:402)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeArray(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:285)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:221)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:387)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMap(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:375)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:237)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:164)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeIterator(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:402)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeArray(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:285)
    .....
    .....
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:221)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMapEntry(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:387)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeMap(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:375)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:237)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeObject(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:164)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeIterator(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:402)
at groovy.json.DefaultJsonGenerator.writeArray(DefaultJsonGenerator.java:285)
```

It seems that both JsonSlurper and JsonBuilder can not handle domain classes built from GORM.

So, is there any elegant way to convert domain classes to JSON string in Micronaut ? Please don't ask me to use Jackson library because the approach way of Jackson is so urgly.

I know in Grails, the converter JSON can convert a domain class to JSON string without any problem. So, is it possible to add the feature of JSON converter into Micronaut just like Grails ?

Comment: You don't have to bother serializing with Micronaut. Just return the object from the controller (make sure to add the object return type) and it will automatically serialize it for you (@Produces defaults to JSON).

Comment: @ToddSharp Thanks. it works. However, if my entity class contains one-to-many children entity classes, then  Micronaut happens to another error: could not initialize proxy [VipLevel#P7] - no Session (through reference chain: Member["VipLevel"]->VipLevel$HibernateProxy$apzZQbKm["levelid"])

Comment: Try annotating your model: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this...

```
@Controller('/member')
class MemberController {


    @Get('/testFetchMember')
    def testFetchMember() {
        Member member
        Member.withTransaction {
            member = Member.findByMemberId('A0001')
        }
        log.info("member.email is ${member.email}")
        def jsonObject = new JsonBuilder(member)
        log.info("check point 1001: finish JsonBuilder")
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toPrettyString()
        log.info("jsonString=" + jsonString)
        return jsonString
    }
}
```

You could do this...

```
@Controller('/member')
class MemberController {


    @Get('/testFetchMember')
    Member testFetchMember() {
        Member member
        Member.withTransaction {
            member = Member.findByMemberId('A0001')
        }
        log.info("member.email is ${member.email}")
        member
    }
}
```

If your controller action returns a POJO/POGO/etc., it will be serialized to JSON using Jackson.

Just an FYI... I would not do the `.withTransaction` stuff in the controller action but that is unrelated to the question posed.

Comment: is the same true for Grails 4? Specifically that simply returning domain instance(s) is sufficient? I can't use the Resource annotation on the domain, as I don't want the scaffolded controller to step on the existing controller logic. (SO isn't letting me @ Jeff ...)

Comment: "is the same true for Grails 4?" - No.

Comment: " I can't use the Resource annotation on the domain, as I don't want the scaffolded controller to step on the existing controller logic." - `@Resource` is a Grails thing but in a Grails app, you can use that without stepping on your existing controller logic.  When you use `@Resource`, we only generate a controller class at compile time for you if you don't already have a controller with the corresponding name.  If you do, that controller will be used instead of the one that would have been generated. Common thing is to provide your own which extends `RestfulController`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Jeff! It looked to me as though it was overriding the controller, but maybe it was overriding the views instead? I'll give it another go.

Comment: "It looked to me as though it was overriding the controller" - If it is, please report that at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we can take a look.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I will. I have a view that makes an ajax call back to the controller, and I've added logging to show when controller methods are hit. Without the annotation, the ajax call hits the method and functions properly. Withe the Resource annotation, it hits the same method in the scaffolded controller, which I know because my custom logging isn't displayed.

Comment: If you have a domain class like `demo.Member` that is annotated with `@grails.rest.Resource`, and you also have a controller called `demo.MemberController`, then the compiler extension should use your `demo.MemberController` instead of generating one.  I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing but if you can, linking that sample app from the issue would be helpful.  Thanks again for the feedback!

Comment: Hi again, @JeffScottBrown - I've reported the issue here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11671. Thanks!